# How to use the SDK in Android studio for developing apps

Tags: android, sdk

I have one SDK based upon which I will make an app. Is there any command or shortcut by which I can use that SDK in my new app? SDK is available on Git.

Answer (score 0):

You do this by adding the library to your project through your application's build.gradle file. Typically library projects hosted in git will have their libs hosted as dependencies on Maven central which you can add to your project with the necessary compile statement. For example

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
```

For a more detailed tutorial, see the answer here: 
[How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)